# Before aspect printing twice

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have the following @Before Aspect where if a method is annotated with my Custom Annotation,
I would land into the Aspect which does a print.

The Aspect works fine but it prints twice, meaning I enter the Aspect twice.

Could I get some advice on why this happens twice when it should only be happening once. Thanks.

Note: This is not in Spring, this is implemeneted in plain Java.

Class with method annotated to trigger Aspect

```
public class ClassUsingUser {

    @RequestValidation(isEnabled = true)
    public String doSomething(User user) {
        return user.toString();
    }
}
```

Custom Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface RequestValidation {
    boolean isEnabled() default false;
}
```

Aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class RequestValidationAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(RequestValidation)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        // this is the issue where I get this printed twice. 
        // but expecting it to happen only once.
        System.out.println("Entered Aspect!!");
    }
}
```

Main method to just trigger the method and Aspect

```
public class SomeMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setName("Fer");

        ClassUsingUser classUsingUser = new ClassUsingUser();


        // based on debug, I seem to hit the following doSomething() line, go to Aspect @Before,
        // come back here and go into Aspect @Before again thus printing twice. 
        String s = classUsingUser.doSomething(user1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Dependencies and Plugins in POM File

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Probably lacking `execution` condition - see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683175/spring-annotation-aop-called-twice).

Comment: I agree. One piece of advice (no pun intended): When developing and debugging aspects, don't print stuff like "entering advice", but always print the `JoinPoint` or `ProceedingJoinPoint` instance. If you had done that, you would have seen that probably one of them printed as `call(..)` and one as `execution(..)`, explaining to you what was happening.